# I think I'm Stuck in Earthbound Zero

Tags: mother

I'm playing Earthbound Zero (MOTHER) on an emulator.  I've reached Magicant and am trying to get through the Crystal Cavern (that's the way out, right?), but I keep dying, especially to the fish.  After dying yet another time, I was, as usual, teleported to the Mysterious Mimicker's house.  But something is wrong.  I can't move, no matter what buttons I push, and the z button won't work either.  The phone-ringing noise keeps going off too.
Please help, I love this game even if it is kinda frustrating and the random encounters just won't stop.  I'm at level 15 and I don't want to lose my progress; I really want to meet Ana.

Comment: Please do not add irrelevant tags, thank you.